# How to search objects by label in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, tools

How can I search and find objects by their label in Inkscape 0.92?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're referring to the id of an object, but this approach might work even if you refer to something else.

Mark nothing or the whole image. Select the xml-Editor with the 4th button from the right in the tools menu, which shows an icon like this: **<>** (Hotkey: Shift+Ctrl+X).

A multipart dialog pops up. Hit *Ctrl-F* for *find* and you get a search field. Now type the id or whatever you're searching for.

Comment: No , Label differs from ID , but that method works for labels as well since it searches the whole xml document.Thanks

Comment: This has been added to the Search+Replace dialog of the development version of Inkscape - it's not going to be in 1.0, though. If you need it, use https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-master/?latest=1

Comment: Well, it turns out, this works ONLY for nodes that are expanded in the XML editor; if you have thousands of nodes within a parent node which is collapsed in the XML editor, it will not be found, neither by id nor by label. What's even funnier, there is no "expand all nodes" button, and you cannot even use the keyboard to expand the nodes - you HAVE to click the little triangle, one by one, for each of the thousands of nodes! How convenient! :)